# MVC4 - EditorFor helper doesn't reflect changes in model nor DefaultValue

Tags: model, asp.net-mvc-4, helper

In my MVC4 project, after action, my HtmlEditorFor helpers do not reflect changes in model properties, and does not take into account `[DefaultValue("Some string ...")]`.

Here how I write the EditorFor code, maybe something's wrong with it ?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
```

But this kind of "pure" html/value line does

```
<h2>@this.Model.SomePropertyThatHasChanged</h2>
```

Thank you if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I added `this.ModelState.Clear();` before `return this.View([View name], [Model]);` and now it works model changes are reflected.

This did not solve the problem of DefaultValues not showing at all.

Comment: But problem: If I do that this.ModelState gets wrong, for example this.ModelState.IsValid is always considerred as Valid.